# Preserve Standalone Comment with Rollup

Tags: rollupjs

I am attempting to preserve a trailing standalone comment with rollup. I briefly looked through extending rollup with a plugin or digging into the AST but am looking for guidance on a possible solution.

**Input**

```
// Some comment

const foo = {};

// Another comment <-- I want this to remain

export { foo };
```

**Output**

```
(function (exports) {
    'use strict';

    // Some comment

    const foo = {};

    exports.foo = foo;

    return exports;

}({}));
```

**Rollup Config**

```
export default [
  {
    input: "src/index.js",
    plugins: [],
    output: {
      file: "dist/index.js",
      format: "iife",
      name: "foo"
    },
    treeshake: false
  }
];
```

Comment: There is no reason to keep comments in a bundle, your bundle should be as light as possible to optimize loading

Comment: A valid reason might be that leaving comments in is the default behavior of rollup...

Comment: Licenses and attributions are a great (and sometimes required) reason to leave comments in a bundle.